# Automapper for member condition

Tags: c#, automapper-6

I am using auto mapper 6.1 and I want to map some values from one object to another, but there is a condition that those values can not be null and not all object properties are supposed to be mapped if so I could easily use ForAllMembers conditions. What I am trying to do is:

```
   config.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>()
     .ForMember(x => x.Branch, opt => opt.Condition(src => src.Branch != null), 
        cd => cd.MapFrom(map => map.Branch ?? x.Branch))
```

Also tried

```
 config.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>().ForMember(x => x.Branch, cd => {
   cd.Condition(map => map.Branch != null);
   cd.MapFrom(map => map.Branch);
 })
```

In another words for every property I define in auto mapper configuration I want to check if its null, and if it is null leave value from x.

Call for such auto mapper configuration would look like:

```
 ClassA platform = Mapper.Map<ClassA>(classB);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the MapFrom, but you need a PreCondition instead. See [here](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Conditional-mapping.html#preconditions).

Comment: I would have loved to see the accepted answer, but the link is dead :( Please add the answer here.

Comment: Updated the link.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood correctly, it may be simpler than you think. The `opt.Condition` is not necessary because the condition is already being taken care of in `MapFrom`.

I think the following should achieve what you want: it will map `Branch` if it's not `null`. If `Branch` (from the source) is `null`, then it will set the destination to `string.Empty`.

```
config.CreateMap<ClassA, Class>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Branch, cd => cd.MapFrom(map => map.Branch ?? string.Empty));
```

And if you need to use another property from x instead of `string.Empty`, then you can write:

```
config.CreateMap<ClassA, Class>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Branch, cd => cd.MapFrom(map => map.Branch ?? x.AnotherProperty));
```

If you want to implement complex logic but keep the mapping neat, you can extract your logic into a separate method. For instance:

```
config.CreateMap<ClassA, Class>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Branch, cd => cd.MapFrom(map => MyCustomMapping(map)));

private static string MyCustomMapping(ClassA source)
{
    if (source.Branch == null)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else
    {
        return source.Branch;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what if I want a value from x instead of string empty.

Comment: @WojciechSzabowicz, I edited my response to add 2 more examples. Hope it helps.

Comment: @AlexSanséau That code will never set destination to `string.Empty` because if `ClassA.Branch` is null, that field will not be mapped. That's the default AutoMapper behavior. `Branch` will have a value of `string.Empty` only if the default constructor for `Class` initializes it that way.